# Independence number of graph with $\varepsilon n^2$ edges

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory

Let $\varepsilon<1/1000$ and $n$ is big enough. Is it true that every graph with at most $\varepsilon n^2$  edges has independence number bigger than $\varepsilon n$?

Comment: I don't think so. Consider a graph consisting of $1/\epsilon$ cliques, each of size $\epsilon n$. It has $ n (\epsilon n-1)/2 \leq \epsilon n^2$ edges and independence number $1/\epsilon$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Will's example is better, but you may also proceed probabilistically.

A random graph $G(n,\varepsilon)$ (every two vertices are joined with probability $\varepsilon$) has at most $\varepsilon n^2$ edges with probability almost 1 and does not have such huge independent sets, also with probability almost 1 (the probability of each set of size $\lceil \varepsilon n\rceil$ to be independent is small as $e^{-Cn^2}$, and the number of such sets is exponential in $n$.)